# Disable appium debug when running test

Tags: ruby, rspec, appium

I run my appium tests on top of rspec and I am always getting debug messages while inspecting/manipulating elements, which is really confusing.
Is there a method to disable this? I was trying to force capabilities (debug=false, logLevel="info") and no luck. Also, when server is running in non-debug mode, I am still getting debug msgs on my test output.

And I am getting this while starting the test:

```
     :caps => {
         :platformName => "android",
           :deviceName => "Android Emulator",
    :newCommandTimeout => 999999,
                  :app => "/Users/kriz/Workspace/builds/my_app.apk",
              :noReset => "true",
            :fullReset => "false",
                :debug => "false",
            :log_level => "info"
}
Debug is: true
Device is: android
post /sessionpost /session
```

Answer (score 3):

Include debug: false in the appium_lib part of the desired_capabilities hash.

```
desired_capabilities = {
  caps: {
    platformName: "iOS",
    versionNumber: '8.1',
    deviceName: device,
    app: APP_PATH,
  },
  appium_lib: {
    debug: false,
  }
}
```

Documentation is spotty on these options, but they're at least commented well in code.
https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/blob/master/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb

Answer (score 2):

When running appium you can use the --log-level flag to suppress debugging messages by setting the level to warn/error:

`appium --log-level warn`

Comment: Yes, I know, but this doesn't make the messages disappear on my console. I was also trying info level. No effect :(.

Comment: The debug messages were coming from the console where rspec was launched, not some other one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below lines of code which worked for me:

```
AppiumDriverLocalService service;
AppiumServiceBuilder serviceBuilder;

serviceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        serviceBuilder.usingAnyFreePort();
        serviceBuilder.usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/bin/node"));
        serviceBuilder.withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/bin/appium"));
        serviceBuilder.withLogFile(new File("./appiumLogs/appiumLogs"+System.currentTimeMillis()));

    HashMap<String, String> environment = new HashMap();
    environment.put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin:" + System.getenv("PATH"));
    serviceBuilder.withEnvironment(environment);

    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(serviceBuilder);
    service.start();
    service.clearOutPutStreams();
```

It will save the logs in the file path mentioned and it will clear the console output logs.

Comment: Yup! This part `service.clearOutPutStreams()` resolved my problem! Appium logs are now not cluttering my IntelliJ console, but logs are correctly added to the defined log file. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

set the below configuration while initiating Appium server:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");
    int port = 4543; // use any not used port number
    //Build the Appium service
    builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();

    builder.withIPAddress("0.0.0.0");
    builder.usingPort(port);
    builder.withCapabilities(cap);
    **builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "warn");** // this is the flag to remove debug logs
    AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    service.start();
```